# How to collect Jacoco code coverage reports in parallel stages pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jacoco

Test stages will be running in multiple Jenkins nodes(4 nodes in total) parallelly, and therefore the code coverage reports are in several nodes and all of them are different. How can I merge them or select the report with highest code coverage rate?